# Insert same character in nth lines with vim

Tags: vim, sequences

I want to insert a sequence of numbers but I need to repeat every number in n lines, I mean:

```
Original file       New file
1                   1,1
2                   1,2
3                   1,3
4                   2,4
5                   2,5
6                   2,6
7                   3,7
8                   3,8
9                   3,9
```

Comment: I don't have time to do the research for a proper answer just now, but look at macros: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros  They allow you to record a sequence of commands and repeat it.

Comment: easier to do with `awk`

Comment: How can I use awk for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `:help sub-replace-expr`. A simple `.*` will match the number, and you can then concatenate the result, using `submatch(0)` to work with the match:

```
:%s#.*#\=(submatch(0)+2)/3 . ',' . submatch(0)#
```

Comment: Hi Ingo, I have another question. Now I need to do insert a sequence until the number that I previously inserted does not change. I mean, Now I want to insert the sequence 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3.

Comment: Try to figure out the math; the _modulo_ operator in Vim is `number % 3`.